# How does temperature affect sound wave dissipation in air?

Tags: temperature, acoustics, dissipation

Sound waves dissipate in any material such as air, but if temperature decreases or increases; how would the increase or decrease in temperature affect the dissipation?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133333/atmospheric-pressures-effect-on-sound?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See equation 8-10 in [this chapter](http://www.mne.psu.edu/lamancusa/me458/10_osp.pdf), which gives sound attenuation as a function of temperature, frequency and water vapour concentration. The relationship [is somewhat complicated](http://gradbena.fizika.si/HarrisJASA66.pdf), but loosely attenuation of sound per distance increases as the air gets colder.